# How to unistall windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service. 
Now I want to unistall it and re-install it but I have this error if I try to install it with this command:

```
InstallUtil.exe GestoreService.exe
```

The error is

> It and exception occurred During Installation .
>   System.ArgumentException : Origin GestoreService already existing in the local computer

How can I fixed this error?

This is the main code:

```
public GestoreService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
    if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("LoggerGestore"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
        "LoggerGestore", "LoggerGestore");
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    log.Error(e);
    }

    log.Info("preparazione file di config in corso..."); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First uninstall the service that's already installed:

```
InstallUtil.exe /u GestoreService.exe
```

Then re-install:

```
InstallUtil.exe GestoreService.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Installed service could not be installed again until it is uninstalled. You need to use /uninstall switch in order to uninstall service, you can learn more about installutil on [Installutil.exe (Installer Tool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(v=vs.110).aspx)

As a additional note if you want to update some of libraries of service *.exe* file then you do not need to uninstall and install it again. All you have to do is to *stop* the service, replace the the old files (Assemblies/.exe) and *start* it again.

```
InstallUtil.exe GestoreService.exe /uninstall
```

Or you can use short for `/uninstall` as `/u`

```
InstallUtil.exe /u GestoreService.exe
```